# Re-displaying CodeIgniter data that isn't validated

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

As I understand it, only values that get validated can be re-loaded on a form if validation fails.  Currently I have the following form

```
    <?php echo form_label('Vendors', 'vendors'); ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('vendors', $vendors, $this->input->post('vendors')); ?>

    <br>

    <?php echo form_label('Title', 'title'); ?>
    <?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title')); ?>

    <br><br>

    <?php echo form_label('Custom Query', 'query'); ?>
    <?php echo form_textarea('query', set_value('query')); ?>

    <br>

    <?php echo form_hidden('id', set_value('id')); ?>

    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit Query') ?>
```

And the following validation rules:

```
'my_rule' => [
    [
        'field' => 'vendors',
        'label' => 'Vendors',
        'rules' => 'required|greater_than[0]'
    ],
    [
        'field' => 'title',
        'label' => 'Title',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ],
    [
        'field' => 'query',
        'label' => 'Custom Query',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ]
]
```

However, my hidden field (id) will not be re-loaded with a value if validation fails because it is not required.  Is there a way around this / am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you add id to your my_rule?

Comment: Because it isn't a required attribute.  The page will update an existing record if `id` is set, create a new record if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have your "id" field in your rules, even if it's not required. You can "not require" it, just have it trimmed for instance :

```
'my_rule' => [
    [
        'field' => 'vendors',
        'label' => 'Vendors',
        'rules' => 'required|greater_than[0]'
    ],
    [
        'field' => 'title',
        'label' => 'Title',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ],
    [
        'field' => 'query',
        'label' => 'Custom Query',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ],
    [
        'field' => 'id',
        'label' => 'ID',
        'rules' => 'trim'
    ]
]
```

Like this, the field will get repopulated after submission, unaltered (except trimmed but I think in you case it doesn't matter)

Comment: Thanks.  Part of me hates adding non-semantic rules to alter behavior, but it definitely worked.  I ended up using xss_clean.